# Android Togglebutton with changeable backgroundcolor?

Tags: android, widget, togglebutton

I want a widget that behaves like a togglebutton and can have its background color changed from code in runtime. Is there such a widget out there?

Or can someone put me in the right direction of how to develop av widget with the desired features? Samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setBackgroundColor(color)`.  It is inherited from the `View` class.